# How to work with repository with module or extension for CMS

Tags: php, git

Lets say I'm working with module for CMS. Files of module can be in a different folders. For example, file structure can look like:

```
/catalog/controller/my_controller.php
/catalog/view/my_view.php
/admin/controller/my_controller.php
/admin/view/my_view.php
```

I want to version my module and at the same time i'd like to keep it in the ready-for-test environment.

While I'm using git what is the best way to work with the repo? Should i keep all the module files in a separate folder? But then I'll need to copy them to actual environment for tests each time perform changes on it.

Or mb can I install git-repo and module to CMS root folder and put all the CMS files to "Ignore List"?

What would you do?

Comment: What sort of files are in your CMS, and is there any source code at all there?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'm been working with many CMS. At the moment the question is theoretical. If you have any ideas how to do it perfect, please, just share.

Comment: So here's the deal: Git is great for storing text, source code, and things like this.  It isn't great for storing binary files, in particular large binary files, which you think might change and therefore get versioned often.  If your CMS contains things like product images, sound files, etc., then by all means don't version that with Git.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen okay, i'm not going to version CMS files. I want to version my module and at the same time i'd like to keep it in the ready-for-test environment. Anyway, thx for you answer - I'll clarify my question at the top

Answer (score 0):

When you are working on the extension you want this extension to be inside working environment. So what you can do is to install your extension into CMS and exclude all CMS files from the git repository with `.gitignore`

```
*
!/README.md
!*/
!*my_controller*
!*my_view*
```